# How to fix a "make sure to use ng-click to call the function" error

Tags: html, angularjs

There seems to be something wrong in my code and I can't tell what it is. When I click run, I get an error that says:

> "On the element, make sure to use ng-click to call the minusOne()
>   function."

I thought there might be a syntax error somewhere but I can't tell.

VIEW CODE

```
<div class="rating">
    <p class="likes" ng-click="plusOne($index)">+ {{ product.likes }} </p>
    <p class="dislikes" ng-click="minusOne($index)">- {{ product.dislikes }}</p>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER CODE

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.title = 'This Month\'s Bestsellers';
$scope.promo = 'The most popular books this month.';
$scope.products = [{
    name: 'The Book of Trees',
    price: 19,
    pubdate: new Date('2014', '03', '08'),
    cover: 'img/the-book-of-trees.jpg',
    likes: 0,
    dislikes: 0
}, {
    name: 'Program or be Programmed',
    price: 8,
    pubdate: new Date('2013', '08', '01'),
    cover: 'img/program-or-be-programmed.jpg',
    likes: 0,
    dislikes: 0
}, {
    name: 'Harry Potter & The Prisoner of Azkaban',
    price: 11.99,
    pubdate: new Date('1999', '07', '08'),
    cover: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b4/Harry_Potter_and_the_Prisoner_of_Azkaban_(US_cover).jpg',
    likes: 0,
    dislikes: 0
}, {
    name: 'Ready Player One',
    price: 7.99,
    pubdate: new Date('2011', '08', '16'),
    cover: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a4/Ready_Player_One_cover.jpg',
    likes: 0,
    dislikes: 0
}];
$scope.plusOne = function (index) {
    $scope.products[index].likes += 1;
};
$scope.minusOne = function (index) {
    $scope.products[index].dislikes -= 1;
};}]);
```

Comment: Are you sure this view code is being controlled by your mainController? (ng-controller or in the $routeProvider)

Comment: Can you provide a plunker(http://plnkr.co/) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At very bottom of your controller code it should try this:

```
$scope.products[index].dislikes += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using it on the div, not the p tag? (Wrap each p in div if needed)